# Implement a Sliding Paged Banner in UIKit

Tags: ios, user-interface, uikit, slide, banner

I'm working on an iOS app and I was hoping to have implemented a *"sliding, paged banner"*, similar to what I saw in the **ComiXology** iPhone app. See the images below:

[image: Fig. 1. "Sliding Paged Banner" as seen in ComiXology]

[image: Fig. 1. "Sliding Paged Banner" as seen in ComiXology when dragged with a finger]

I'm at a loss on how to implement it. A link to a tutorial would help, or at least an idea of how to go about implementing it. Thanks. :D

**I'm using UIKit to develop my app.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of UIScrollView and UIPageControll.  Apple has an [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) of this.